# Java - Sockets, application not answering

Tags: java, sockets

Hello, i'm trying to make an java game. Right now i'm at the server part. Right now the output is that it just freze's and wont complete. I've tried using wireshark but ya didn't go to well.

Sorry for my english.

**The Server:**

```java
    while(acceptingSockets){
        if(playersOnline != maxPlayers){
            playersOnline = playersOnline + 1;
        socket = ss.accept();
        brr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));                      
        bw.write("ACCEPTED");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
        }else{
        bw.write("DENIED");
        bw.flush();
    }

        while (acceptingConnections) {
            while ((brr.readLine()) != null) {
                String line = brr.readLine();
             if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")){
                bw.write("MAP-" + mapId);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("NEWMAP");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("CONNECTED");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                brr.close();
                bw.close();
                socket.close();
             }
            }
        }
```

**The Client:**

```java
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
            prep = true;
            start.setEnabled(false);
            start.setText("Connecting");
            try {
                socket = new Socket(Display.Ip, Display.port);
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
                String line;
                while(prep){
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){  
                        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("ACCEPTED")){
                            ps.println("CONNECTED");
                        }
                        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")){
                            new Display();
                            dispose();
                            br.close();
                            ps.close();
                            socket.close();
                            prep = false;
                        }
                        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("NEWMAP")){
                            Display.newMap = true;
                        }
                        if(line.startsWith("MAP-")){
                            String newLine = line.replace("MAP-", "");
                            Display.mapId = Integer.valueOf(newLine);
                        }
                    }
                }

          }  catch (IOException e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
              new Message("No Server Found!", "The servers are offline!.", MessageType.WARNING);
              start.setText("Connect");
              start.setEnabled(true);
                prep = false;
                    }
          }});
```

Comment: I do not get any errors, I Added printStackrace at the client side and it woudnl't anyway paste any errors. And on server same, no error

Comment: Where did you switch the boolean value of `acceptingSockets` and `acceptingConnections`?

Comment: are your client/server on the same network

Comment: Never yet, where going to implement that as the server got full. But i thod it was better fixing this first.

Comment: Yes, we are on the same network. Have tried with an VPS to, same result
EDIT: If it matters, The VPS OS is ubuntu and mine is Windows 7.

Comment: Ah ok. Any idéa of what problem it can be?

Comment: Add traces that write to the console so you know you get passed accept on the server and passed connect on the client. No you just don't see anything.

Comment: btw what was the problem with wireshark ?

Comment: Coudln't get it open. It just crashed when selected internet connection

Comment: The client calls readLine(), but the server does not send any lines.

Comment: It seems that this is another OP who is allergic to debugging and thinks that looking at source code is an efficient way of removing bugs:(

Comment: Ok, i got wireshark to not crash after some hours. And ready to use it. thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Call 'bw.newLine()' after sending text, eg. "ACCEPTED" from the server, else the client readLine() call will not return.

Comment: WTF?  What do you mean, 'doesn't work'.  When you run the client and server code under your debugger, where does it get stuck/raise exeception/loop/order pizza/whatever??   Sod this, downvote and close-voting as off-topic 'cos no debug info:(

Comment: By doesn't work i mean the same problem as before. It doesnt read even the first message(ACCEPTRED)

Comment: Again. what did you find out when you ran your debugger?  Does the server successfully execute the 'bw.write("ACCEPTED");, bw.newLine(); bw.flush();'??  If it does, what happens at the client.  Does a breakpoint on 'if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("ACCEPTED"))' get hit?  If so, what is the value of 'line'??  DEBUGGER!

Comment: You have the code for both server and client in front of you.  You have all the code, you have the environment, OS, everything.  We have some text in an SO post.  Why is getting posters to do some debugging like pulling teeth?

Comment: I mean, you still don't know if the problem is at the server, the client or both.  Without wireshark, you cannot cut the problem in half - a first step in troubleshooting of any system.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. You need to send a line terminator.
2. You're calling `readLine`() far too many times. If the result doesn't match what you're comparing it to each time, you're just throwing it away. You should only call it once per loop iteration, in the `while` condition, thus:

   ```
   String line;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```